# ～にしては vs. ～としては

Tags: particles, particle-に, particle-と

I know one implies the thing I'm comparing actually *is* the thing I'm comparing it to, and the other doesn't.

Can someone suggest an easy example or trick for remembering which is which?

Answer (score 14):

Just adding to an existing answer because I typically don't think of these two as comparisons, I look at it from a different angle than the OP.

I typically think of this as more of expectation rather than comparison for ～にしては, although comparison could be valid as well but I never think of it like that.

So as @istrasci pointed out, ～にしては means "Considering X is Y...". There is an expectation involved because it typically goes against what the speaker is expecting from X.

From @istrasci's example, we have

> トムはお金持ちにしては、あまりぜいたくな人生をおくらない(Considering Tom is pretty rich, he doesn't lead a very luxurious lifestyle)

Normally we usually expect rich people to lead a luxurious life, but in this case, Tom does not lead a luxurious life, therefore it goes against an expectation. So it is used to contrast a reality (does not live a luxurious life style) to some kind of expectation (rich people typically live in luxurious life style)

Another example:

> スキーは初めてだと聞いていたが、それにしては、なかなかうまく滑るじゃないか。(I heard this is (your) first time skiing, considering this is (your) first time, you were pretty good)

This is another example of contrast between reality (you were a first time skier and you were pretty good), to an expectation (first time skiers are not good)

For me ～として implies and empathize some kind of position.

> 弁護士であるわたしとしては、それを勧めるわけにはいかない (As a
>   lawyer, I cannot recommend (doing)
>   that)

Lawyer is a position being empathized here.

> 学生として参加する (Apply/join as a student)

Student is a position being empathized here, I don't just want to apply, I want empathize that I want to apply as a Student.

Comment: Probably a different question, however, にしては seems very similar to のに or だけど. If you were to replace にしては with のに or だけど the meaning wouldn't change significantly, right?

Comment: @phirru yeah I guess it wouldn't, but I personally havn't seen nishite wa used more often as noni or dakedo. The contrast between these is a very good question on its own and I think you should ask it.

Answer (score 8):

～にしては means "Considering X is Y, ..."

> トムはお金持ちにしては、あまりぜいたくな人生をおくらない (Considering Tom is pretty rich, he doesn't lead a very luxurious lifestyle

～としては mean "As a / In the capacity of X, ..."

> 弁護士であるわたしとしては、それを勧めるわけにはいかない (As a lawyer, I cannot recommend (doing) that)

<s>So the latter is when the thing actually *is* the thing you're comparing to.</s>

Comment: Your answer contradicts with pg 502 of DBJG. In the notes they write that `Xにしては` presupposes "is X". And `Xとしては` says may or may not be X.