# How are として、としては and にしては different?

Tags: grammar

How are として、としては and にしては different? I understand how to use として totally fine but the other two, I get lost on.

Comment: としては is simply として＋は: [Why としては instead of として](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27379/43676)

Comment: Related https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/762/45489

Answer (score 4):

**としては**：「Nounの立場から言えば、・・・。」という意味です。
It attaches to nouns that describe a person or organisation and state what it is like for that position.

> 例1) 私個人としては、納得できません。
> I personally can't agree.

> 例2) 学校としては、アルバイトをしていいと言うことができません。
> As a school, we can't say that it's okay to have a part-time job.

**にしては**：Aにしては、B。＝ 「Aから考えると、Bは予想外だ。」という意味を表します。

It's used to evaluate or criticise something. It’s used when you want to say that what you expected about A was different from the actual B. There is a feeling that it's unexpected.

> 例1) あの子は、子供にしては難しい言葉をよく知っている。
> That child knows difficult words well for a child.

> 例2) このおすし、100円にしてはおいしい！
> This sushi is delicious for 100 yen!