# 「としては」と「にしては」の違い＆交換する可能？

Tags: grammar

彼女は、女性**としては**力が強い

上の文には「としては」を「にしては」にチェンジする可能がありますか？

なかなか難しいですが、ご解説いただけますでしょうか。

Comment: Related or dup [How are として、としては and にしては different?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/96156)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

結論から言うと、一般に置き換えることは出来ないが、曖昧な時に置き換えても良いのです。

> ①「彼は英語教師にしては優等だ」
>
> ②「彼は英語教師としては優等だ」
>
> ③「彼は英語教師にしては相談に乗れなかった」
>
> ④「彼は英語教師としては相談に乗れなかった」
>
> ⑤「彼女は女性にしては力が強い」
>
> ⑥「彼女は女性としては力が強い」

①では、話し手は英語教師とは違う分野に優等さを示した彼を賞賛している。

②では、話し手は彼が周りの目に優等な英語教師とみなされていることを断言している。

③では、話し手は何らかの問題があって、英語教師に解決させてもらえられると思って、彼に聞いたが、英語教師でありながら何の役にも立てなかったことで怒れて怒鳴っている。

④では、話し手は何らかの問題があって、英語教師に聞いたが、駄目だったことを断言している。

⑤では、話し手は彼女が普通の女性よりも力が強いことを賞賛・疑問している。（音調と文脈による）

⑥では、話し手は彼女が普通の女性よりも力が強いことを単に断言している。

「にしては」と「としては」の使い分けについて解説します、

「にしては」には１つの意味しかありません。

或る資格や立場を題目として取り立て、当然期待される姿から現実の姿が大幅に離れていて、その資格や立場に相応しくないことを表す用法。**話し手の感情が色濃く反映され**、文脈によって、賞賛・疑問・皮肉・非難などが含まれる。例文：「初めての料理にしては上出来だ」

一方、「としては」には２つの意味があります、

一つ、「にしては」とほぼ同じ意味で、或る資格や立場から求められる姿と現実の姿の**ずれを客観的に表す用法**。例文：「山としてはそんなに高くはない」

二つ、或る人の立場で言うと、との意味で、主に人物を題目として取り立て、立場や視点を表す用法。係助詞「は」で置き換えることも出来るが、他の人たちはどう思っているか、という対比の意識は消える。「にしては」にこの用法はない。例文：「彼は英語教師としては優等だ」

Comment: つまり、（1）この場合、彼はずっと日本語の先生でいたかもしれませんが、英語を教えるのも上手だと気づいてから驚きました。この場合には「にしては」が使える可能性がありますね。似たような状況でなければ、「にしては」は使えませんね。

Comment: @JudyHarry いいえ、その逆です、英語教師でいて日本語を教えるのも上手ですね。それに、驚いたを賞賛に訂正します。

Comment: 見間違えてすみませんTAT。「彼は英語教師にしては（別の分野も）優れている」ということですね。

Comment: お忙しい中、ご指導ありがとうございました。説明に長い文を書いてくれてありがとう。SHINKUさんのように気長に教授してくれた人に出会えてよかったのです。

Comment: よく勉強しました。また、ありがとうございました。(*^▽^*)